# how to add binary file to buildroot generated image?

Tags: buildroot

How can i include a pre-built binary file into buildroot generated image?

I have tried to include the binary file into appropriate folder in build_dir but every time i try to do make the image is being created without the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a root filesystem overlay.

See chapter [Project-specific customization](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize) in the Buildroot manual.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is looking for a easy fix you can add the files to buildroot-dir/files folder. The file should match the exact directory structure. For example you want to put the file in /usr/bin in the image then keep the file in buildroot-dir/files/usr/bin and rebuild the image.

Comment: is this documented anywhere?